# How to use delete request with axios in react project and Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I need to delete the element but don't know how to get that specific element!
This is the structure of data on Firebase
[image]

And this is the code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import classes from "./Goal.css";
import Button from "../UI/Button/Button";
import axios from '../../axios-goals'

const Goal = () => {
    const [goal, setGoal] = useState({
        goals: [],
        error: false
    });

    const deleteGoalHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        axios.delete("/goals.json")
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => error => {
                setGoal({error: true})
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/goals.json')
            .then(response => {
                const fetchedGoals = [];
                for (let key in response.data) {
                    fetchedGoals.push({
                        ...response.data[key],
                        id: key
                    })
                }
                setGoal({goals: fetchedGoals, error: false})
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setGoal({error: true})
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className={classes.MyGoals}>
            {goal.goals.map(goal => (
                <div key={goal.goalData.goalName} className={classes.Goal}>
                    <h3>{goal.goalData.goalName}</h3>
                    <p style={{fontSize: '13px', color: '#cbcbcb'}}>{goal.goalData.commentToGoal}</p>
                    <div className={classes.GoalDetails}>
                        <p>{goal.goalData.importance}</p>
                        <p>{goal.goalData.timer}</p>
                    </div>
                    <form>
                        <Button btnType="Success">DONE</Button>
                        <Button btnType="Danger" clicked={deleteGoalHandler}>CANCEL</Button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Goal;
```

When you press the cancel button, chosen element must be deleted from Firebase. It seems that my url is wrong because it deletes all the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call:

```
axios.delete("/goals.json")
```

Firebase will indeed *that* node, which means it deletes all of your goals.

If you want it to delete a specific node, you will need to specify the path of that specific node:

```
axios.delete("/goals/-MRMLoUzCCLA2A3xRWeb.json")
```

So you'll need to pass the key of the clicked goal to `deleteGoalHandler` from the HTML, and then pass it to the database goal. Luckily you already store it in the `id` property for each goal, so it should be something like this in the JSX/HTML:

```
clicked={deleteGoalHandler(goal.id)}
```

Comment: Won't it delete only the first element because I need to delete the chosen one?

Comment: The `delete` call in my answer is an example of what it would look like to return the first node in your JSON. The JSX in my examples passes in `goal.id`, and you then need to pass that in the URL to the REST API.

Comment: Hey @Max. Did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

of course you are deleting the whole document.
It has to be:

axios.delete(`/goals/${id}.json`);

where the id variable has been passed from your goals variable